# Implement Soft delete with cascade type DELETE in Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I've implemented soft delete in my spring boot application. Which looks something like:

**Program.java**

```
public class Program{
    //other attributes
    private boolean deletedFlag;

    //getter setters       
}
```

And in repository of `program` entity, I'm firing following query to only return the entities, which has deleted flag `false`.

```
public interface ProgramRepository{
    //other methods
    Program findByDeletedFlagFalse();
}
```

So this implementation works perfectly fine. But the problem is, I've an another entity (named 'Major'), in which I've injected list of `programs`. So `major` entity looks like:

```
public class Major{
    //other fields
    List<Program> programs;
    //getter setters
}
```

Now, when I delete program entities, it still appears in the major, even if they are deleted. So basically my response looks like:

```
"major":{
      //other fields
      "program": [{
           //other fields
           "deletedFlag": true
       }]
 }
```

But the expected behavior should be like if we delete child entity, parent should not list it. So what am I missing here?

Is there any alternative of implementing soft delete in spring boot? I've already seen this: [Hibernate Soft Delete using update Cascade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23990008/hibernate-soft-delete-using-update-cascade), But it seems like the answer using hibernate instead of Spring data JPA.

I've already seen this: [Handling soft-deletes with Spring JPA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19323557/handling-soft-deletes-with-spring-jpa), but it is more aligned to hibernet solution instead of spring data JPA.

Comment: Read about Cascade delete [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7197181/234110)